# Error opening a file with date/time stamp in its name

Tags: python

I want to create a file with date and time stamp appended to the file name using Python. When I am doing this, I am getting the error while opening the file.

```
today = datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%m-%d-%Y_%H:%M:%S")
file = "text" + today
open(file,'w')
```

It reports error for invalid file name.

Comment: on my environment works fine but it could because of the colons

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but it just might be that the name of the file is invalid (i.e. it contains prohibited characters, for example colon)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
today = datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%m-%d-%Y_%H.%M.%S")
fname = "text" + today
f = open(fname,'w')
```

1. As already stated, don't use colons i filename (I changed it to a simple dot, you can change it to whatever you want).
2. You need to make an object from `open(...)`, which I called `f`, but you might already know that.
3. `file` is a built-in function. Don't use as variable name.

#### Update

Oups. I remembered wrong about that `w+`-part. Sorry,

Answer (score 1):

Colon (`":"`) is not allowed in file name on some of the operating systems.